# How can I output integers only?

Tags: python, for-loop

Here is my code

```
list = [1,2,3]
for i in list:
    print(i)
```

This is the output

```
1
2
3
```

What I'm looking for

```
1, 2, 3
```

Comment: `print(', '.join(str(i) for i in list))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If python 3
`print(i, end =", ")`

If python 2 append a comma to the print to escape the newline
`print(i),`

Answer (score 0):

A mixture of generators and join

```
lst = [1,2,3]
print(','.join(str(i) for i in lst))
```